# Providing an object for a field in constructing an object in Guice

Tags: java, guice

Suppose I have class Z, which injects class A:

```
class Z {
  @Inject
  public Z(.., A arg, ..) {
    ..
  }
}
```

Suppose class A has this constructor:

```
@Inject
public A(B arg0, C arg1, D arg2) {
 ...
}
```

I want injection to work normally, except in special cases, where I want to provide one of the arguments. e.g., Constuct A using cObject of C class. Note that A is itself constructed using Z.

I want this because I am writing a functional tests for Z, where I want to provide different kinds of fakes depending on the test. One test file will contain only one kind of fake for B, or C, or D.

Comment: May be a builder pattern can help?

Comment: @Octopus, can you explain how? Thanks.

Comment: `Builder` pattern helps you to pass any number of arguments based upon the requirement. You can just pass only the arguments that are needed. Please checkout builder pattern whether it fits your requirement

Comment: If you need it for testing, consider avoiding dependency injection and provide all dependencies manually. That way you'll almost certainly get better code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [`Modules.override`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Modules.html#override%28com.google.inject.Module...%29) here, which has documentation about its use for functional testing. Use it sparingly, as things can get very messy and hard-to-follow otherwise, but it would look like this:

```
@Before
public void createInjector() {
  this.injector = Guice.createInjector(
      Modules.override(new YourZABCDModule()).with(new AbstractModule() {
        @Override public void configure() {
          bind(B.class).to(FakeB.class);
        }
      }));
}
```

Or, as in the `Modules.override` documentation, just use smaller modules for more-granular combinations:

```
@Before
public void createInjector() {
  this.injector = Guice.createInjector(
      new ZAModule(),
      new FakeBModule(),
      new CModule(),
      new DModule());
}
```

Comment: In my case, I would be overriding with mocks. I think I should prefer Modules.override in this case, yes?

Comment: It depends entirely on how granular your modules are, and whether you're trying to replace a full module's worth of bindings or just one out of a large module. There's no single best practice for module layout and granularity, so pick the one that works the best with YOUR module structure. Good luck!